# How to check what `wondershaper` has done?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, networkmanager

I used this command:

```
sudo wondershaper eth1 20 20
```

to limit network traffic. The command shows no errors.

But I need a command or network monitor or gui which confirms this limitation. For example, it says that this connection is limited to 20 kb download. So that I'm sure system considers it as a rule. In particular, I may check the condition after a disconnection/reconnection, reboot, etc,

Answer (score 2):

Wondershaper is just a front-end of sorts to `tc` which is the one that manipulates the "traffic control settings" and this tool includes the `-statistics` which is what you're aiming for. The thing is that it shows stats of defined objects, namely `qdisk` or `class` or `filter` or `action` or `monitor`, so you need to cast a `-s` call on each object to get an overview (that is, if you can interpret it) of the different rules.

You can see the current rules also using `sudo wondershaper ethX` (I didn't know about this one) which is an shortcut to most of the last without having to manually input everything.

Now, a most down-to-earth test would be pinging while you're actively using the down/up stream, and compare it when you do the same using wondershaper rules.

Look for a comprehensive tool like `mtr`.